# Npm errors while I try to install dependencies in loopback (strongloop) webapp

Tags: node.js, npm, loopbackjs, strongloop

I am new in the NodeJS world. I have created an loopback(strongloop) webapp, but after it I try to run the `npm install` command in the application's folder I get this output in the terminal (Ubuntu server 14.04 withd newest updates - in a vagrant instance)

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:/vagrant/example-app$ npm install
npm WARN package.json example-app@1.0.0 No license field.
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing ycssmin@1.0.1
npm WARN deprecated jsonstream@1.0.3: use JSONStream instead
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing request@2.62.0
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing loopback-explorer@1.8.0
npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-62-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v4.1.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.3
npm ERR! path ../node-uuid/bin/uuid
npm ERR! code EPROTO
npm ERR! errno -71
npm ERR! syscall symlink

npm ERR! EPROTO: protocol error, symlink '../node-uuid/bin/uuid' -> '/vagrant/example-app/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/node_modules/.bin/uuid'
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-62-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v4.1.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.3
npm ERR! path npm-debug.log.2d5bb41273f18b2da30958b9aa61bfe6
npm ERR! code ETXTBSY
npm ERR! errno -26
npm ERR! syscall rename

npm ERR! ETXTBSY: text file is busy, rename 'npm-debug.log.2d5bb41273f18b2da30958b9aa61bfe6' -> 'npm-debug.log'
npm ERR!

npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /vagrant/example-app/npm-debug.log
```

This is the generated `package.json` which has been generated by loopback framework:

```
{
  "name": "example-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "server/server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "pretest": "jshint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "compression": "^1.0.3",
    "cors": "^2.5.2",
    "loopback": "^2.22.0",
    "loopback-boot": "^2.6.5",
    "loopback-datasource-juggler": "^2.39.0",
    "serve-favicon": "^2.0.1"
  },
  "optionalDependencies": {
    "loopback-explorer": "^1.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "jshint": "^2.5.6"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "",
    "url": ""
  },
  "description": "example-app"
}
```

I have tried to run with `sudo npm install` but I have gotten exactly the same result.

**Versions:**

- Node v4.1.0
- Npm  v2.14.3
- Vagrant 1.7.4
- Ubuntu Server 14.04.3 (with the newest updates)

Here is the [npm-log file](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=D21E97023AD7FDB4!93904&authkey=!ANLlzFpuYvX8O6Y&ithint=file%2Ctxt), it's very long.

*If you know my mistake, do not hesitate, just answer :)*

Comment: `synced_folder` does not support symlinks. So I think that the best practice is move your project directory to other folder (eg. /home/ubuntu/) and run `npm install` again.

Comment: Or you can try with command: `npm install --no-bin-links`

Answer (score 4):

This is a problem with Vagrant/VirtualBox. Unfortunately, the synced/shared filesystem doesn't support symlinks.

If you don't require this functionality, the easiest thing to do is to just disable it in your `Vagrantfile`:

```
# ...
config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", disabled: true
# ...
```

If you do require it, you may be able to find a work around now that you know it is a problem with symlink support, which npm uses for creating bins :-)

See https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/synced-folders/basic_usage.html for more details.

Answer (score 1):

The error happens, because your mounted shared directory (/vagrant) is on file system which doesn't support symbolic links.

To void this, you need to tell `npm` that your file system doesn't support symbolic links, e.g.

```
npm config set bin-links false
```

<sup>Source: [npm doesn't work in vagrant at GH-7308](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/7308#issuecomment-73653002)</sup>

or by specifying `--no-bin-links` argument for [`npm install`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install) which will prevent npm from creating symlinks for any binaries the package might contain.

---

Alternative way is to append this to your [`package.json` file](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json), e.g.

```
"config": {
  "bin-links": false
},
```

Answer (score 0):

As said above, the synced/shared filesystem doesn't support symlinks.

SO, you can install **node.js** on your Windows host and execute `npm install` in the host code directory