# Error in NPM installing express via package.json

Tags: express, npm, vagrant

My node and npm versions are recent. 
But getting error and no express folder is coming up under ./node_modules.
Express folder is coming up under /home/vagrant/.npm
npm-debug.log is generated. Not sure how to attach that.

```
npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-68-generic
npm ERR! argv "/home/vagrant/.nvm/versions/node/v4.2.2/bin/node" "/home/vagrant/.nvm/versions/node/v4.2.2/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v4.2.2
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.7
npm ERR! path ../mime/cli.js
npm ERR! code EPROTO
npm ERR! errno -71
npm ERR! syscall symlink

npm ERR! EPROTO: protocol error, symlink '../mime/cli.js' -> '/vagrant/testProject/node_modules/express/node_modules/send/node_modules/.bin/mime'
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-68-generic
npm ERR! argv "/home/vagrant/.nvm/versions/node/v4.2.2/bin/node" "/home/vagrant/.nvm/versions/node/v4.2.2/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v4.2.2
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.7
npm ERR! path npm-debug.log.f7bc0249588f17bea044ac621dd74bb9
npm ERR! code ETXTBSY
npm ERR! errno -26
npm ERR! syscall rename
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Npm errors while I try to install dependencies in loopback (strongloop) webapp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32666983/npm-errors-while-i-try-to-install-dependencies-in-loopback-strongloop-webapp)

Answer (score 4):

You need to run npm with `-–no-bin-link` option to tell npm that your filesystem doesn't support links

If you want to do the `--no-bin-link` on each npm command, you can add an alias to your `.bashrc` file in your home directory with this command:

```
echo "alias npm='npm --no-bin-links'" >> /home/vagrant/.bashrc
```

Another possibility is to set your configuration to allow symlinks on Windows hosts in your Vagrantfile

```
config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
    v.customize ["setextradata", :id, "VBoxInternal2/SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate/vagrant", "1"]
end
```

see https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/7308 for more detail

Comment: Have to find a way to include the option in package.json

Comment: not sure it can be included but its an option from CLI when you run `npm install` just add the option

Comment: Of course the option worked at the CLI. Thats why marked ur answer as useful.

Comment: Editing with another possibility from vb option

Comment: can you explain more on this vb option?

Comment: you need to set this option from your Vagrantfile

Answer (score 2):

You should tell `npm` that your file system doesn't support symbolic links, e.g.

```
npm config set bin-links false
```

<sup>Source: [npm doesn't work in vagrant at GH-7308](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/7308#issuecomment-73653002)</sup>