# Why Express creates a Sym link while Installation?

Tags: node.js, express, symlink

Recently saw that express creates a symbolic link while installation. PoC: [Try installing express on Vagrant](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S7Awt.png). You would get an error that it can not create a symbolic link. To prevent the error you would have to use **--no-bin-links** flag. The Question is, Why is it required for express to create a symbolic link and if we prevent creating symbolic links, does it make a difference in the way of execution?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As per the sources, You can skip the symbolic links with the below command :

> **npm config set bin-links false**

It seems that few linux versions doesn't support file system symbolic links.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34013177/error-in-npm-installing-express-via-package-json)